# RHEL 9 : bash: subscription-manager: command not found

Tags: redhat

something is messed up in my system and now i cannot access rhel repos.
subscription manager itself is not there. How do it install subscription manager.

Comment: Have you checked the system to see if the binary is there? To me, it just looks like the  $PATH is not set correctly. Try to search the system after "subscription-manager", it is probably located in /usr/bin or something/bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subscription-manager` is located here:

```
/usr/sbin/subscription-manager
```

If you are missing it you can mount a installation CD and install package:

```
yum localinstall /cd/mountpoint/BaseOS/Packages/subscription-manager-1.27.16-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what i ended up doing. Installing it from the ISO/USB drive